# Proving that if $x$ is a multiple of $3$, then $x + 1$ is not a multiple of $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $x$ is a multiple of $3$, then $x + 1$ is not a multiple of $3$. This is a rather obvious fact, but I don't think I understand the solution.

> Suppose that $x$ is a multiple of $3$ but, for the sake of contradiction, that $x + 1$ is likewise a multiple of $3$. Then $x = 3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x + 1 = 3t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $3k + 1 = 3t$, so $3k - 3t = 1$ and hence $3(k-t) = 1$. Therefore $k - t = \frac{1}{3} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is a contradiction, so $x + 1$ not a multiple of $3$, as desired.

The problem here is that the deduction $k - t = \frac{1}{3}$ followed by multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{3}$, when division is not defined in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this allowed? I'm trying to find another way to prove this from the axioms. Another possibility is to simply argue that $3 \mid 3(k-t)$ so $3 \mid 1$, which is an absurdity, as the only divisors of $1$ are $\pm 1$, and be done at that step.

I'd appreciate some feedback on whether each of these two proof strategies are correct and which would be preferable in this instance.

Comment: When you divide by 3, you are no longer in $\Bbb Z$ but in a bigger set $\Bbb Q$. It is probably cleaner to say that $3(k-t)=1$ implies that $3$ divides $1$, a contradiction: the only divisors of $1$ are $1,-1$

Comment: @markvs Am I allowed to do that, though, when I'm working in $\mathbb{Z}$? I'm in effect using the properties of $\mathbb{Q}$ to deduce (lack of equality) in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Z$ is inside $\Bbb Q$ then "working" in the smaller set implies "working" in the bigger set, but I have explained how to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @markvs How do you prove that the only divisors of $1$ are $1$ and $-1$ without "working" in $\mathbb{Q}$? The proof I've seen relies on showing that if $|d|>1$, then $\left|\frac{1}{d}\right|<1$ and hence cannot be a divisor of $1$.

Comment: Let $1=mn$ for some integers $m,n\ne 0$. Then if $m$ or $n$ is negative, replace it by its negative and $1$ by $-1$. So you get $\pm 1=mn$ where $m,n>0$. Then the LHS is $1$ (because the RHS is positive). Then $mn\ge m$ and $mn\ge n$. Hence $1\ge m, n$, so the integers $m,n$ are $1$. As you can see, rational numbers are not needed.

Comment: The fact that 1 is not a multiple of 3 is a fact that can be proven without any reference whatsoever to the field of rational numbers.  It is a fact about integers, plain and simple.

Comment: Both are correct. Since $\,a\mid b\,$ in $\Bbb Z\iff \frac{b}a\in \Bbb Z$ one can use fractions to (dis)prove divisibilities, and in more complex problems fractional arithmetic may prove simpler, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3982134/242) for an interesting important example. More generally [Consecutive Numbers are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2046362/242), and the proofs there may prove illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $ x $ is a multiple of $3 $ but, for the sake of contradiction, that $x+1$  is likewise a multiple of $3$ . Then $x=3k $ for some $ k\in \Bbb{Z }$  and $ x+1=3t $ for some $t\in \Bbb{Z}.$ Then $3k+1=3t$ ,

$3k−3t=1 $ and hence $ 3(k−t)=1$

As, $k, t\in \Bbb{Z}\implies s=k-t\in\Bbb{Z}$

And $3s=1$.

Implies $3|1$ , which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

What is done by the proof is the following:

1. First, the set of integers is closed under addition and subtraction. So as $k$ and $t$ are both integers, then so must $k-t$ be an integer.
2. Algebra was used to derive the equation $3(k-t)=1$, and thus $k-t = 1/3$. If an equation is true in a field [here $\mathbb{Q}$], then it remains true if you multiply both sides by a nonzero element in the field [here $\frac{1}{3}$].
   ETA: Or if you prefer, that the equation $3(k-t)=1$ holds and $3$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$, gives $(k-t)$ cannot be an integer after all.
3. Putting 1. and 2. together yields the desired contradiction as both cannot be simultaneously true.

I will elaborate on Step 2. For the claim to be true in the first place, what is actually needed is that $3$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$; put another way, there is no other integer $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $3a$ is $1$. In fact this result would *not* hold if we were working in a ring where $3$ has a multiplicative inverse; these exist, an example is $\mathbb{Z}/M\mathbb{Z}$ for any integer $M$ satisfying $\gcd(M,3)=1$.

Comment: The OP  understands the proof which you copied. The question is why the division by $3$ is possible when working in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I'm curious if this is another way to say the following. Treat $k-t$ as a variable (say, real). Then $3(k-t) = 1$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence a unique solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ if $k-t \in \mathbb{Z}$; otherwise, it has no solution. We found a solution in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{Q}$, but it's not an integer. If there were some integer solution, the solution in $\mathbb{R}$ would not be unique, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: I'm probably overly complicating it quite a bit, but is the logic of what I said above sound?

Comment: @markvs I saw that and editted. I am not sure what is meant precisely by "working in $\mathbb{Z}$". In particular, there is no reason why one cannot multiply both sides of an equation by a nonzero rational.

Comment: @JohnT or you could use the fact that if an equation is true in a field, such as $\mathbb{Q}$, then the equation is still true after multiplying by a nonzero element in the field, here $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Mike: When you divide by $3$, you are working in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: The key for the result to hold though, is that $3$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$. If we were to replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a ring where $3$ does have a multiplcative inverse then the result would not hold.

Comment: Meanwhile, what is the problem, mathematically, with "working in $\mathbb{Q}$" in the first place?